# Update matching rows from lists

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Column1    |  Column2 | Column3
sky        |  blah    | Null
giraffe    |  blah    | Null
apple      |  blah    | value
```

And 2 lists:

```
List1 = [sky, gold, giraffe]
List2 = [blue, yellow, tall]
```

I am looking to match some of the values in Column1 with values from List1, and update Column3 rows that are found with values from List2. List1 and List2 items have the same index to match each other, so the matching value for sky is blue, etc. So I am trying to insert 'blue' in Colum3, on the 'sky' row IF the field is Null.

What's the neatest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch entries from each list, and try to do an update for each such pair:

```
for name, value in zip(List1, List2):
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE MyTable
                      SET Column3 = ?
                      WHERE Column1 = ?
                        AND Column3 IS NULL''',
                   (value, name))
```

This can be even further simplified:

```
cursor.executemany('''UPDATE MyTable
                      SET Column3 = ?
                      WHERE Column1 = ?
                        AND Column3 IS NULL''',
                   zip(List2, List1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just part of an answer but could be a useful beginning.

Use pandas to put your two lists into a table in the database with the other table. Then write some sql to do the actual updating.

I will come back to this if I think to do so.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> List1 = ['sky', 'gold', 'giraffe']
>>> List2 = ['blue', 'yellow', 'tall']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'List1': List1, 'List2': List2})
>>> df
     List1   List2
0      sky    blue
1     gold  yellow
2  giraffe    tall
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('c:/scratch/temp.sqlite')
>>> df.to_sql('Lists',conn)
```

Just to complete my answer:

```
update temp
set column3 = (select List2 
                            from Lists
                            where List1 = temp.Column1)
where Column3 is null
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, much appreciated, it worked so far. I'm new to sqlite, but I imagined it would look something like:

Comment: `update 
  table1 r1
set
  (
    r1.column1, 
    r1.column2
      ) = (
    select
      r2.column1, 
      r2.column2
    from
      Lists  r2
    where
      r2.column1 = r1.column1
    and
      rowid = 1    
     )
    where exists (
      select 
        null
      from 
        Lists r2
      where 
        r2.column1 = r1.column1
      ); ` > but it's not working with sqlite3?